# ES6-like templating in ES5 - doesn't work when attribute names have .'s in

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-5

I found this function [here](https://medium.com/@zackargyle/es6-like-template-strings-in-10-lines-a88caca6f36c), which allows ES6-like templating in ES5.

```
String.prototype.eval = function(data) {
return this.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g, function(_, code) {
    var scoped = code.replace(/(["'\.\w\$]+)/g, function(match) {
      return /["']/.test(match[0]) ? match : 'scope.' + match;
    });
    try {
        return new Function('scope', 'return ' + scoped)(data);
    } catch (e) { return ''; }
});
```

}

It works very well, except for when attribute names include .'s (dots) in them.
My regex skills aren't up to scratch, how can I enable it to deal with attribute names that include .'s (dots)?

i.e. "MY_ATTRIBUTE" works whereas "MY_ATTRIBUTE.A" does not.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest a properly, maintained templating library, rather than something with such a basic oversight in it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the thing I'm working on at the moment has me restricted to ES5 with no libraries

Comment: What exactly is `["'\.\w\$]+` supposed to match?

Comment: Instead of trying to insert `scope.` in the right places (for which, to do it properly, you'd need a complete transpiler), just use a `with (scope)` statement in your function.